# images with dropzone in vue with laravel mix

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, dropzone.js, laravel-mix

I'm using Dropzone to upload images in SPA using vue.js, althought the path is correct but images don't appear don't know why!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibZ7v.png)
the screenshot with vue dev tool

the code i use

```
<img
        :src="imageObject.data.attributes.path"
        :class="classes"
        ref="userImage"
        :alt="alt"
    >
```

and code in controller

```
$data = request()->validate([
        'image' => '',
        'width' => '',
        'height' => '',
        'location' => ''
    ]);

    $image = $data['image']->store('user-images', 'public');

    $userImage = auth()->user()->images()->create([
        'path' => $image,
        'width' => $data['width'],
        'height' => $data['height'],
        'location' => $data['location'],
    ]);

    return new UserImageResource($userImage);
```

and in User.php model i used

```
public function coverImage()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserImage::class)
        ->orderByDesc('id')
        ->where('location', 'cover')
        ->withDefault(function ($userImage) {
            $userImage->path = 'user-images/cover-default-image.png';
        });
}
```

and same with profileImage method
and for the resource

```
return [
        'data' => [
            'type' => 'user-images',
            'user-image-id' => $this->id,
            'attributes' => [
                'path' => url($this->path),
                'width' => $this->width,
                'height' => $this->height,
                'location' => $this->location,
            ]
        ],
        'links' => [
            'self' => url('/users/'.$this->user_id)
        ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, finally by editing the path in the resource to be

```
return [
        'data' => [
            'type' => 'user-images',
            'user-image-id' => $this->id,
            'attributes' => [
                'path' => url('storage/'.$this->path),
                'width' => $this->width,
                'height' => $this->height,
                'location' => $this->location,
            ]
        ],
        'links' => [
            'self' => url('/users/'.$this->user_id)
        ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

this might happen, the data is not present when component is rendered, after data load component should rerender, try one of the two approaches,

```
1. 
<img    v-if="imageObject"
        :src="imageObject.data.attributes.path"
        :class="classes"
        ref="userImage"
        :alt="alt"
    >
```

```
2.
<img    :key="imageObject.data.attributes.path"
        :src="imageObject.data.attributes.path"
        :class="classes"
        ref="userImage"
        :alt="alt"
    >
```

Comment: No, it didn't work in both
I think in 1-laravel storage or 2-dropzone itself